# gSOAP multiple definition building error in eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, gsoap

i want to use gSOAP for create  web service for my project in eclipse cdt.
in command line gsoap generated file compile and run with no error. but when i import the file in eclipse and build them i got this error :

```
multiple definition of `soap_serve(soap*)' soapServer.cpp
```

how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include "soapServerLib.c" or "soapClientLib.c" in your project. Those are to be used for libs only.